# Calculating time period of a rotating rigid body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rigid-body-dynamics

I am given the following problem:

A cuboid is rotating around the $AB$ axis at $t=0$, with no external forces acting on the cuboid.

[image]

The lecturer question is:

> "When will the cuboid symmetry axis return to its initial
>   position after $t=0$?"

The lecturer gave the following answer, which I cannot understand.

> In other words, we are asked when will the cuboid return to its initial position.
>   Since angular momentum is conserved, the symmetry axis is rotating about the angular momentum vector **(Why?)**,
>   so in fact, we are looking for the precession frequency of the symmetry axis about the angular momentum.

**My question:**

1.Why the symmetry axis is rotating around the angular momentum vector?

2.Why when the symmetry axis returns to its initial orientation (in relation to the angular momentum vector), the cuboid also returns to its initial orientation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why the symmetry axis is rotating around the angular momentum vector?

For a square cuboid such as this, the principal axes are through the center of mass and are either in the plane containing the square faces(projected to the center) or normal to it. Since the axis $AB$ is not a principal axis, the angular velocity vector traces out a cone about the angular momentum vector.

> 2. Why when the symmetry axis returns to its initial orientation (in relation to the angular momentum vector), the cuboid also returns to its initial orientation?

Currently, I'm torn between "it's obvious" and "this is not necessarily the case." I'll update my answer when I hash it out.

Comment: I have also had the feeling that it is "obvious", but for some reason I feel quite uncertain.

Comment: Btw, tell me if I'm wrong: the principle axes go through the center of mass since the body rotates around the center of mass, and they may have normal XYZ direction since the body is symmetric along those directions when looking from the center of mass point, and a symmetry axis is a principle axis.

Comment: @Taru -- The principal axes (note well: not principle axes) of a cuboid with three distinct edge lengths are parallel to the edges. A diagonal is not a principal axis. The principal axes of a square cuboid in which two of the three edges have equal length but the third is distinct are a bit trickier. One is clear: It's parallel to the edges with the unique length. That the other two lengths are equal means any direction in this plane qualifies as a principal axis. A diagonal: Not a principal axis. A cube: That's simple. Any axis is a principal axis.